# Usort on Array of DateTime Objects in PHP - No Error, Array Not Sorting

Tags: php, datetime, usort

I have a long multi dimensional array including some DateTime objects. I want to sort the entire array based on the [startdate] object. I'm using this usort function (based on a lot of online resources and modifications from various errors). It's not sorting the array.

My array is formatted as follows. Showing only the start for brevity.

```
Array
(
    [] => Array
        (
            [startdate] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2019-04-10 19:00:00.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => America/New_York
                )

            [starttime] => DateTime Object
                (
                    [date] => 2019-04-10 19:00:00.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => America/New_York
                )
```

Here is my usort code:

```
function date_compare($a, $b) {
    $t1 = $a["startdate"]->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $t2 = $b["startdate"]->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');           
    return $t1 - $t2;
}    
usort($allEventsSimple, 'date_compare');
```

I also tried sorting the DateTime objects using this code:

```
function date_compare($a, $b) {
    $t1 = var_dump($a[startdate]);
    $t2 = var_dump($b[startdate]);          
    return $t1 - $t2;
}    
usort($allEventsSimple, 'date_compare');
```

Comment: Just do `strtotime($a["date"]) - strtotime($b["date"])`. You will also need to loop over the elements of the base array.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat the `startdate` values are `DateTime` instances. You cannot use those in `strtotime()`, it will throw an error ~ _"PHP Warning:  strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given"_

Comment: This is giving me the error: Warning: strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given.

Comment: Missed that, try `strtotime($a['startdate']->date) - strtotime($b['startdate']->date)` @AmyMcGarity-GermanPearls

Comment: `$dateObj->getTimestamp()`

Comment: @Beginner I can't see `getTimestamp` in the dump, it might not work.

Comment: @roundAbout it's a method of `DateTime` ~ https://www.php.net/manual/datetime.gettimestamp.php

Comment: @AniketSahrawat there is no `date` property of [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/class.datetime.php)

Comment: @Phil I understand that it's a method which is inherited from `DateTime` but I don't think it is present in the above case.

Comment: @AmyMcGarity-GermanPearls https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php

Comment: @roundAbout it totally is. See where it says `[startdate] => DateTime Object`? That's saying the value of that array key is an instance of `DateTime`. What you're seeing underneath that is just the debugging properties

Comment: @Phil I can see a field named `date` in `startdate`.

Comment: @AniketSahrawat you're right (demo https://3v4l.org/iMHUP). Not sure why but my local PHP version (PHP 7.2.15-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) complains if I try and use it. Perhaps because it's undocumented

Comment: @Beginner getTimestamp() worked - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually do have errors, you just can't see them (see [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php))

Your code would be producing

> PHP Notice:  A non well formed numeric value encountered in ...

This is because you're attempting to subtract one non-numeric string from another.

If you're using PHP 7, you can directly compare `DateTime` instances with the awesomely named [*"spaceship operator"*](https://www.php.net/manual/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.spaceship-op), eg

```php
return $a['startdate'] <=> $b['startdate'];
```

[image]

---

If you're stuck on PHP 5, compare timestamps

```php
return $a['startdate']->getTimestamp() - $b['startdate']->getTimestamp();
```

Comment: No, I'm on php 5.6

Comment: @AmyMcGarity-GermanPearls that's why I provided a PHP 5 version

Comment: Thank you. I didn't see it - nothing past the image loaded.

Comment: @AmyMcGarity-GermanPearls can you see it now? If not, try reloading this page